# Send Data back and forth from Python Script to the Browser Running ReactJS Application

Tags: python, reactjs, sockets, networking, p2p

I have some python script which meant to do some data processing, for data visualization in 3D the traditional libraries like matplotlib 3d plot isn't sufficient for the job, I came up with Idea that using WebGL to do the visualization job since I have some experience with it.

Is it possible to send data from python script using for example P2P connection(on the same machine) to the react app created using create-react-app(which is accessible from http://localhost:PORT_NUMBER)?

For example when the python script sends the following JSON string to the browser:

```
"{
 object-id:cat,
 x-move: 2,
 y-move:6
}"
```

Cat object in the WebGL canvas moves 2 pixels in the x-direction and 6 pixels in the y-direction.

Comment: Certainly, I'm not looking for the client-server model in which we put NodeJs in between.